# SQLite Android RunTimeError

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to follow [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/androidtutorial/) tutorial (Part 3) about getting SQLite Database to work with Android application. I've made some changes to the content but the code should be the same. The android application crashes after it opens without displaying anything and this is the output from LogCat:

> 11-25 11:42:43.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.munroproject/com.example.munroproject.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "drop": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE munro (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, area TEXT, height TEXT, grid TEXT, drop TEXT, feature TEXT, country TEXT, geographurl TEXT, latitude TEXT, longitude TEXT)

and this is the contents of the database helper:

```
package com.example.munroproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "munro_directory";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE munro (" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name TEXT, " +
        "area TEXT, " +
        "height TEXT, " +
        "grid TEXT, " +
        "drop TEXT, " +
        "feature TEXT, " +
        "country TEXT, " +
        "geographurl TEXT, " +
        "latitude TEXT, " +
        "longitude TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String inputvalue = "Ben Chonzie,Loch Tay to Perth,931,NN773308,645,cairn/shelter,S,NN7732430857,56.453851,-3.992057");
    String[] msplit = inputvalue.split(",");
    int j=0;
    values.put("name",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("area",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("height",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("grid",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("drop",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("feature",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("country",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("geograph",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("latitute",msplit[j++]);
    values.put("longitude",msplit[j++]);
    db.insert("munro", "name", values);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS munro");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

And the mainActivity file looks like this:

```
package com.example.munroproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected ListView munroList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        munroList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void search(View view) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, height, region FROM munro WHERE name || ' ' || height LIKE ?",
                                            new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.munro_list_item,cursor,new String[] {"name", "height", "region"},new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.height, R.id.region});
            munroList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are putting "drop" inside the base and it is reserved word. Try changing name somehow.

Answer (score 1):

"drop" is a reserved keyword in SQLite used to drop (or delete) tables. If you really want to use it, you can, by enclosing it in double quotes. See example below

```
CREATE TABLE "[tablename]" ("drop" text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sqlite` `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is Autoincrement by default no need to specify `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` In addition sql has inbuilt command `drop` so change the `column/attribute` name